# How can I display an alert that shows the value of a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, alert

I have a javascript file displays a popup `alert` that has a value with a value of a `var`
Must I use:

```
var errorSite = "Web4All";

function displayError{
    alert("There has been an error on " && var errorSite && "!")
}
```

I want to have an alert that says:

> There has been an error on Web4All!

Comment: concatenation in JS is `+` not `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `+` to concatenate:

```
alert("There has been an error on " + errorSite + "!")
```

---

Note you would *not* use the `var` keyword here, which would declare a *new* "errorSite" variable (and not use the already existing one you already declared)!